# Test panic with Randomness::random() 'attempt to subtract with overflow'

Tags: pallet, random

Sorry for the title but I don't know how to explain it better.

I have [this simple custom pallet](https://github.com/Datagen-Project/Datagen-Substrate-Grant/tree/impl_random_selection_from_list/pallets/random_node_selector/src) and I try to test the `create_random_number` dispatchable function with a simple `assert_ok!` but I get this error from the terminal:

```
running 2 tests
test mock::__construct_runtime_integrity_test::runtime_integrity_tests ... ok
test tests::crate_random_number ... FAILED

failures:

---- tests::crate_random_number stdout ----
thread 'tests::crate_random_number' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', /rustc/263edd43c5255084292329423c61a9d69715ebfa/library/core/src/ops/arith.rs:240:1
```

The test panic at [this line](https://github.com/Datagen-Project/Datagen-Substrate-Grant/blob/bf14dc39e31a37fd52b3e5561a4128f135e1de9f/pallets/random_node_selector/src/lib.rs#L186) but I don't understand why because if I try to `cargo build --release` and call this function on the polkadot app it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that the block-number is 0 when your test runs.
The coinflip pallet then tries to calculate `0-1` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ca1f81cd0864ae0614aaff07fa121d2d42110586/frame/randomness-collective-flip/src/lib.rs#L79).
You can set the block-number to 1 in your `new_test_ext` function like this:

```rust
pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
    let mut ext: sp_io::TestExternalities = system::GenesisConfig::default().build_storage::<Test>().unwrap().into();
    ext.execute_with(|| System::set_block_number(1));
    ext
}
```

Many tests do that, for similar reasons, so its not a red-flag.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Now it works fine :)